# preg match and replace

Tags: php, preg-match

here i have some content with some links .in this code i want to replace all those links with modified links
the Fucction `get_web_page` gives me the modified links.

```
$text='<a href="http://tinyurl.com/2tx">google</a>dfhjksdf sdjfkhdskjf sddsf <a href="http://tinyurl.com/d8r">Microsft.com</a>';

preg_match_all('/<a [^>]*href="?([^">]+)"?>/', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $ht)
{
    $new_link=get_web_page($ht[1]);
    $new_link=$new_link['url'];
    echo $gg=str_replace($ht[1], $new_link, $text);
}
```

in above code everything is working fine except the foreach loop the loop is repeating the output and in first output only firest link is replaced. in second out only second link is replaced.

the output is like this

```
<a href="http://www.google.vg/">google</a>dfhjksdf sdjfkhdskjf sddsf <a href="http://tinyurl.com/d8r">Microsft.com</a>

<a href="http://tinyurl.com/2tx">google</a>dfhjksdf sdjfkhdskjf sddsf <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx">Microsft.com</a>
```

i want it to replace all the links at once and the output should the input `$text` with modified links.

can anyone tell me where i am going wrong ?

Comment: It's true that it is possible to use `Regex` to parse html... _But_ is not it easier to use Dom Parser instead of struggling to somehow manage that your regex worked for different inputs?

Comment: i dont know how to use DOM
i am a newbie

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Comment: i have done that with dom but still stuck at that look
that loop is replacing only 1st link